# (node:25033) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning building Vanilla Forums

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build Vanilla Forum on Ubuntu but I have this error when I do "./bin/release".

I am using Ubuntu and I have installed everything that was needed until I got stuck here.

```
[...]
Skipping automatic JS build because VANILLA_BUILD_DISABLE_AUTO_BUILD env variable is set to "true".
00h00m00s 0/0: : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'install'
/home/luis/Escritorio/vanilla
\n==================== Running Command ====================
(node:25033) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'green' of undefined
    at promptRequiredText (/home/luis/Escritorio/vanilla/bin/scripts/utils.js:23:24)
    at promptVersion (/home/luis/Escritorio/vanilla/bin/scripts/utils.js:45:12)
    at run (/home/luis/Escritorio/vanilla/bin/scripts/buildRelease.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/luis/Escritorio/vanilla/bin/scripts/buildRelease.js:82:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(node:25033) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:25033) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I don't know what happend.

I don't know how to interpret it.

Thanks.